# How to download the prerequiste from a particular remote URL location?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, setup-project, setup-deployment, setuptools, prerequisites

I have a setup project created for a C# application. I want to add a prerequiste flash player to this application such that it is downloaded from the remote "adobe website". 
The location of the prerequisite which is on remote adobe server is

> "http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/flashplayer_square_p2_64bit_activex_092710.exe"

In order to achieve this I did the following--
 1) Right click on Set up project and goto properties
2) click on prerequistes button.
3) select the 3rd option "Download prerequiste from the following location" and enter the url    **"http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/flashplayer_square_p2_64bit_activex_092710.exe"**    pressed OK.
4) build the set up project.
5) As a result of building I got 2 files, app.exe & app.msi in the release folder of my project.

BUT PREREQUISITE IS NOT COMING WHEN I INSTALL MY TARGET APPLICATION. 
plz can anyone let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a link in your other post: [How to install flash player from adobe site while installing my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000200/how-to-install-flash-player-from-adobe-site-while-installing-my-c-application)

Please use the edit feature instead of creating separate threads each time you have an update.