# How to install flash player from adobe site while installing my C# application?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, setup-project, setup-deployment, custom-action, prerequisites

I have created a setup project for my C# application. I want to install flash player before my C# application installs. The flash player installation should happen from the online location

> http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/flashplayer_square_p2_64bit_activex_092710.exe

How to prompt the client for installing flash player from the above location, before installing my C# application.

> I thought of adding a project to my
>   solution, which will install the flash
>   player from the above location. Later,
>   add the "primary output of this new
>   project" to the custom actions. But I
>   am not finding C# code snippet to
>   install the flash from above location.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Add it as a prerequisite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334436/adding-custom-prerequsites-to-visual-studio-setup-project

Answer (score 1):

While creating Setup file in C# you can specify the pre-requisite which can be either downloaded from Manf. URL or can be from same setup.